# Проблема с кодировкой в docker

Tags: python, linux, docker

Есть `json` вот такого вот формата, который парсится в программе:

```
[
  "ООО Один",
  "ООО Два",
  "ООО \"Три\" (3379)"
]
```

При запуске программы в `docker` и попытке спрсить файл, возникается следующая ошибка:

```
  File "app/handlers/delegate/basic_delegate_handler.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.special_list = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Без `docker` на основной машине все работает. Еще интересно то, что в ошибке сказано про `ascii`, хотя файл сохранен в `utf-8`.

Изначальный образ использую `ubuntu:16.04`.

Comment: какой образ используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: Нужен не изначальный образ, а тот образ в котором вы запускаете.

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что по умолчанию почему-то в системе стоит кодировка `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'`. Как поменять на `UTF-8` ? Образ `faoxis/ubuntu_flask`.

Comment: кодировка сохранения никак не влияет на кодировку интерпретации, в тексте документа могут быть всякие encoding-комментарии, но *просто текстовый файл* никоим образом не объявляет свою кодировку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш Dockerfile

```
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

Это установит locale по умолчанию

Answer (score 3):

Если вы читаете json из файла, то явно укажите кодировку (крайне вероятно, что utf-8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

with open("special_list.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    special_list = json.load(file)
```

Ваш код работал вне docker, так как `open()` использует `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`кодировку по умолчанию и у вас была настроена utf-8 локаль.

В docker у вас вероятно локаль не настроена, что равнозначно C/POSIX локали, которая использует ascii кодировку.

Не следует менять локаль только для того чтобы прочитать файл в другой кодировке (хотя может быть полезно utf-8 локаль установить по другим причинам).